# Return choice in radiobutton Tkinter function

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I try to set a function to create a radiobutton widget dynamically (based on function arguments). I would like to call this function and that it returns me the choice I made in the radiobutton selection.
With the code below, it is stuck with the value of the first radio button (which I understood is the default value). Thanks !

```
def radiobox(frame, size_checkbox, *text_label):
    var = tk.IntVar()
    for k in range(size_checkbox):
        radiobox = tk.Radiobutton(frame, text=text_label[k], variable=var, value=k) 
        radiobox.pack()
    
    choice = text_label[var.get()]
return choice
```

Comment: Please look at some tkinter/event driven programming tutorials. Most of the time you aren't supposed to call functions that just get the user's input like that. You should make a function that handles the user input after they have clicked using bindings/commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tkinter's `wait_variable` to have the execution of your function pause until the variable has been set.

Here's a simple example that illustrates the technique, though I don't actually recommend this specific example as something you should do. The thing to notice is that the `radiobox` function will not return until the user has made a choice due to the use of `wait_variable`:

```
def radiobox(frame, size_checkbox, *text_label):
    var = tk.IntVar(value=-1)
    buttons = []
    for k in range(size_checkbox):
        radiobox = tk.Radiobutton(frame, text=text_label[k], variable=var, value=k)
        radiobox.pack()
        buttons.append(radiobox)

    frame.wait_variable(var)
    choice = var.get()

    # destroy the buttons
    for rb in buttons:
        rb.destroy()

    return choice
```

Comment: Thanks it works ! It appears to be very useful for radiobutton widget. It's a bit ugly but it does the work :)

Answer (score 0):

GUI frameworks like `tkinter` are usually "event-driven" which is a processing paradigm where the logic flow within the program is driven by events such as user actions, messages from other programs, and hardware inputs from device such as keyboards and mice — see [event-driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). This means that the procedural or [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) way of programming that you are probably familiar with can't be used.

In this case that means that waiting for the user to make a choice as you're trying to do must be done it a different manner. In the code below, a function is called whenever one of the `Radiobutton`s is pressed and the function set the value of the `IntVar` accordingly — but it doesn't "return" anything.

One way to do something sort of like that would be to temporarily "pop-up" a dialog window when the user clicks on the <kbd>Done</kbd> button (or closes the dialog window).

A runnable example illustrating how to do these things is shown below.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, width, height, title=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.title('Choose' if not title else title)
        self.geometry(f'{width}x{height}')

        self.choice = 'nothing'
        self.radiobox(3, 'Label 0', 'Label 1', 'Label 2')
        tk.Button(self, text='Done', command=self.close_down).pack()

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close_down)

    def radiobox(self, size_checkbox, *text_label):
        self.var = tk.IntVar(value=-1)
        for k in range(size_checkbox):
            tk.Radiobutton(self, text=text_label[k], variable=self.var, value=k,
                           command=self.radio_button_pressed).pack()

    def radio_button_pressed(self):
        self.choice = self.var.get()

    def close_down(self):
        showinfo(title='Information', message=f'You chose {self.choice}')
        self.destroy()


app = App(200, 100, 'Select one:')
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It's not exactly what I would like to do but I keep in mind this structure, I'm sure it will be useful.